# jQuery: Get index from each element into a div or after H4 tag

Tags: jquery, database, checkbox

According to the below code:

```
$('#permisosPerfiles div').children('h4').length();
```

This results = 5, But I would get the index of each h4 and index of each checkbox for a while and range each Area (Find, Create, Delete, Edit).

[image]

```
<h3>Asignación de permisos</h3>
    <div id="permisosPerfiles">
        <div id="leftPermisos">
        <h4 id="Usuarios">Usuarios</h4>
        <p>
        <label for="pCrearUsuario">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearUsuario" name="Usuarios[]" value="Crear" type="checkbox" />
        <label for="pBuscarUsuario">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarUsuario" name="Usuarios[]" value="Buscar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarUsuario">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarUsuario" name="Usuarios[]" value="Modificar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarUsuario">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarUsuario" name="Usuarios[]" value="Eliminar" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>

        <h4 id="Clientes">Clientes</h4>
        <p>
        <label for="pCrearCliente">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearCliente" name="Clientes[]" value="Crear" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarCliente">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarCliente" name="Clientes[]" value="Buscar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarCliente">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarCliente" name="Clientes[]" value="Modificar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarCliente">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarCliente" name="Clientes[]" value="Eliminar" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>

        <h4 id="Mps">Marca, Producto Subproducto</h4>
        <p>
        <label for="pCrearMPS">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearMPS" name="Mps[]" value="Crear" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarMPS">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarMPS" name="Mps[]" value="Buscar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarMPS">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarMPS" name="Mps[]" value="Modificar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarMPS">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarMPS" name="Mps[]" value="Eliminar" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightPermisos">
        <h4 id="Poliza">Póliza</h4>
        <p>
        <label for="pCrearPoliza">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearPoliza" name="Poliza[]" value="Crear" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarPoliza">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarPoliza" name="Poliza[]" value="Buscar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarPoliza">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarPoliza" name="Poliza[]" value="Modificar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarPoliza">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarPoliza" name="Poliza[]" value="Eliminar" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>

        <h4 id="Servicio">Servicio</h4>
        <p>
        <label for="pCrearServicio">Crear</label>
        <input id="pCrearServicio" name="Servicio[]" value="Crear" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pBuscarServicio">Buscar</label>
        <input id="pBuscarServicio" name="Servicio[]" value="Buscar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pModificarServicio">Modificar</label>
        <input id="pModificarServicio" name="Servicio[]" value="Modificar" type="checkbox"/>
        <label for="pEliminarServicio">Eliminar</label>
        <input id="pEliminarServicio" name="Servicio[]" value="Eliminar" type="checkbox"/>
        </p>
    </div>
```

I hope I have explained.
Regards!

**EDIT**

This is what I do with the indices of each area and checkbox:

```
NumH4 = 0
NUmH4 = $('#permisosPerfiles div').children('h4').length(); //5
WHile <= NumH4
     numCheckBoxes = 0
     numCheckBoxes = //Code to get total of checkboxes after each $this H4
     while <= numCheckBoxes
         //Code to set checked/unchecked according to data obtained from the database 1 = checked, 0 = unchecked
     numCheckBoxes++;
numH4++;
```

The below image, is a structure of the table from my database that I get 1 or 0 to check or unchecked!

Perhaps the question or the title this poorly written but because my English is not very good, can not explain correctly the question! Need to chat with someone to make me understand better.

[image]

Comment: Your English is confusing me. I haven't quite understood what you are trying to ask. You want to iterate through each of the `h4` tags, then through each of the `input` checkboxes to check whether or not they are checked?

Comment: Im so sorry for my english but right now I want to know just how to get the index of each h4 tag please!

Comment: Given that HTML, what output would you expect/want the jQuery to generate? *Just* the index of each `h4` element, or the index and its text, or `id`..?

Comment: I want get index of each h4 tag into a div #permisosPerfiles, ie, h4#Usuarios will be 1, h4#Clientes will be 2... and get index of each checkbox after h4 tag!

Comment: Yes, but that's going to give you some numbers. How do you want to associate the index with a particular element? Or is it just the numbers that you want?

Comment: I try do a two while to range all Areas (Usuarios, Cientes, Mps, Poliza, Buscar) and for each Area, range each checkbox (Buscar, Modificar, Eliminar, Modificar)!

Comment: @SoldierCorp: and I still don't understand what you're hoping for, I'm sorry if it seems like I'm trolling your question, but could you please *show* the output you want to get, then we'll be better able to help you achieve your aims.

Comment: Check the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/YY8DD/), is this anywhere near? Though I have to leave the getting/setting of the checked/unchecked to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the index of an element, use the following:

```
$("#element").parent().index($("#element"));
```

You always take the parent of the element you need the index of.

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSRct/) for you that puts the indexes in the HTML (just to show which indexes it are).

Comment: `.index(elem)` works just as good and saves some extra work jQuery would have to do else. Keep the calls to `$` as low as possible... ;)

Comment: ok :).. and how I can get index of each checkbox after each H4? Grateful if you help me with that

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? What's the goal of this question?

Comment: @SoldierCorp that works the exact same way. In that case the `<p>` would be the parent of the `input`s

Answer (score 0):

If you want ids of checkboxes that are under a H4 tag (that is what you were asking right ??), you can use the below code

```
$("#permisosPerfiles h4").each(function(index, elem) {
    console.log($(this).text());
    var h4id=$(this).attr('id');
    console.log($('#'+h4id+'+p input:checkbox').length);
});
```

You can replace console.log with the action you want to perform. Here is the jsFiddle I created for it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xajat007/vwNzp/).